# Reading CSV file And Show Data

Tags: c#

I'm bit puzzle with some basic and now I decided that I should take help. I have simple .csv file with following data:

[image]

And I need following output:

[image]

I have already done it but in my coding, I'm reading column name with hardcoding. This will cause issue if column will change their position like below:

[image]

I think this can be done easily using for loop but I'm struggling at this stage. So please be kind and guide me.

my hardcoded code is as follows:

public override System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection ExtractSamples()
{
ObservableCollection samples = new ObservableCollection();

```
            List<string> lines = this.GetTextLines();

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] parts = line.Replace("\"", "").Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    parts[i] = parts[i].Trim();
                }

                Sample sample = new Sample(parts[1].Trim()); //for reading sample name Test1, Test2
                samples.Add(sample);

                sample.AddResult(DateTime.Now, "C1", parts[2]); //for adding Sample headers and it's Value like C1, 0.001692
                sample.AddResult(DateTime.Now, "C2", parts[3]);
                sample.AddResult(DateTime.Now, "C3", parts[4]);
            
        }

        return samples;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it by using a library called CsvHelper:
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

The example is taken(modified a little) from the CsvHelper site and demonstrates a while loop:

```
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = new List<CsvData>();
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            var record = new CsvData
            {
                C1 = csv.GetField("C1"),
                C2 = csv.GetField("C2"),
                C3 = csv.GetField("C3")
            };
            records.Add(record);
        }
    }
}

public class CsvData
{
    public string C1 { get; set; }
    public string C2 { get; set; }
    public string C3 { get; set; }
}
```

Let me know if there is anything unclear. Also it would be good if you posted what you have coded so far.

**Update related to comments**

```
List<string> lines = this.GetTextLines();

var c1HeaderIndex = lines[0].FindIndex(x => x == "C1");
var c2HeaderIndex = lines[0].FindIndex(x => x == "C2");
var c3HeaderIndex = lines[0].FindIndex(x => x == "C3");

sample.AddResult(DateTime.Now, "C1", parts[c1HeaderIndex]);
sample.AddResult(DateTime.Now, "C2", parts[c2HeaderIndex]);
sample.AddResult(DateTime.Now, "C3", parts[c3HeaderIndex]);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I have edited my code (hardcoded code). Can you check what I should do to make it dynamically?

Comment: @ShalabhSaxena Upfront before looping through the columns in the csv file you can get the index of the column header "C1, C2 and C3" with code similar to the following: ``var c1HeaderIndex = lines.FindIndex(x => x == "C1");`` and adding the index in the ``sample.AddResult(DateTime.Now, "C1", parts[c1HeaderIndex]);`` By getting the column headers index before looping, you can be certain to fit the data dynamically.

Comment: actually it is a good suggestion but it will not work as this is a csv file and data is as follows:  first line: " C1, C2, C3" second line: "0.001692, 0.010725, 7.90E-05"

Comment: You will need to get the "C1, C2 and C3" indexes from the first line. I have added code to my answer.

Comment: every time when I'm trying, it is returning -1.

Comment: That means it cannot find what you are looking for. Can you post the code?

Comment: Thank you dear for your time and all help. I was manage to fix my problem in a different way. However the logic you mentioned also helped to conclude the problem and reach out to solution. Thank you again. Cheers !!